# How to expose SCSS variables from a gem into a rails project with a single `@import`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, rubygems

I have a rails project and a gem. The rails project has `.scss` files that require variables from the gem:

**Rails Project**

application.scss:

```
@import "gem-styles.scss";  
@import "my-scss-file-that-needs-access-to-variables.scss"
```

my-scss-file-that-needs-access-to-variables.scss:

```
color: $primary-color;
```

**Gem**

in gem-styles.scss:

```
@import "common/variables";
```

in common/_variables.scss:

```
$primary-color: #00d9ff;
```

Doing this, I get the error: `Undefined variable: "$primary-color".`

I can include `common/variables` in `my-scss-file-that-needs-access-to-variables.scss` to fix the issue:

`@import "common/variables";`

but I don't find that solution DRY enough. I would have to import `common/variables` into every `.scss` file that requires them. I would prefer to be able to only import one `.scss` file from the gem which contains all of the variables that I need exposed in my parent application, as well as the rest of the styles from `gem-styles.scss`.

Answer (score 0):

you can just paste this `@import "common/variables";` into your application.scss only once.

```
@import "common/variables";
@import "gem-styles.scss";  
@import "my-scss-file-that-needs-access-to-variables.scss"
```

like this

Comment: but then I'm still importing two `.scss` files, I would like to only import one, is this possible?